# c# operator == cannot be used (string to char)

Tags: c#, string, char

How do I make it so the == does work on the string and char.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a;

        // get random lowercase letter
        Console.WriteLine(RandomLetter.GetLetter());
        a = Console.ReadLine(); 

        if (a == RandomLetter.GetLetter())
```

the Error
'Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char''

```
        {

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Simplest solution is calling `ToString()` on the character. You could also use `a.Length==1 && a[0]==c` which is less readable, but produces less garbage (an advantage in a tight loop, a bad tradeoff in your example).

Comment: Call `ToString` on the `char` as in `if (a == RandomLetter.GetLetter().ToString())`.

Comment: the error says it all!! you can not compare `string` and `char` like you cannot compare `pizza` and `shakira` ! they are not the same type

Comment: @chouaib OP seems to understand the problem, he's asking for a solution. And obviously... `Pizza > Shakira`.

Comment: @Rotem: in that case, I gave a clear *hint*, you just didn't grab it... hint to my hint: `shakira` should be eaten like a `pizza` but she has to be converted first `ToPizza()` before doing so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna read just a character use `Console.ReadKey` method

```
char random = RandomLetter.GetLetter();
Console.WriteLine(random);
char input = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar; 

if (random == input)
```

Comment: What if you want to compare A? I suppose the SHIFT will return before you type the a.

Comment: @FDL no ReadKey method returns a ConsoleReadKey info. You can use Modifiers property to see which special buttons are pressed  simultaneously (like shift, ctrl etc.) `KeyChar` will return the pressed character.

Comment: Correct, but you have to skip it manually. On the other side the ReadLine method doesn't read the Modifiers so you can retrieve the first char directly, but I assume you will need to press the Return Key.

Answer (score 0):

```
(a == RandomLetter.GetLetter().ToString())
```

The `ToString()` override on all objects can be used to change anything into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

```
if (a == RandomLetter.GetLetter().ToString()) ...
```

---

```
if (a.Length == 1 && a[0] == RandomLetter.GetLetter()) ...
```

---

But as other answers mention, in your particular case you're probably better off just reading one character from the console anyways.

Comment: `a[1]` will pose a problem.

Comment: @PatriceGahide Sorry, I'm working in a 1-based language at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

`Console.ReadLine()` reads the whole line as a `String`, so it can't be compared directly to a single character. You either need to convert your character to a `String`, so it can be compared (`.ToString()`), or instead read a single key inputted by the user, e.g. using `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` instead of `Console.ReadLine()`.

You'll want to use the former if the idea is to allow the user to input a line of characters and check if it consists of a single, specified character. If you want to read a single key press, use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing just the first letter of the string to the char (because a string is just an array of type char). By doing it this way, if the user enters more than you want, the program wont crash.

```
char myChar = 'a';
string myString = "a";

if (myChar == myString[0])
{
    Console.WriteLine("it's a match");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

- `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` to get only the first typed char.
- `Console.ReadLine().First()`, but it allows the user to write an entire sequence of characters.

Be careful with the `ReadKey` method because it allows user to press *SHIFT*, *CTRL* or any other key even if they haven't a "written" representation, if you intend to compare only "writable" chars.